# Некорректо работают операторы сравнения ">=" "<=" в формуле Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Написал вот такую формулу: `=SUMPRODUCT((F15='Входящие SPLIT'!$S$2:$S)*('Входящие SPLIT'!$A$2:$A>=$D$14)*('Входящие SPLIT'!$A$2:$A<=$E$14)*('Входящие SPLIT'!$R$2:$R))`, подсчитывает сумму значений в столбце соответствующий нескольким условиям. Два из которых, это "дата от" и "дата до" (период):`('Входящие SPLIT'!$A$2:$A>=$D$14)*('Входящие SPLIT'!$A$2:$A<=$E$14)` Все бы ничего, но только "дата до"($E$14), день который выставлен в этой ячейке не учитывается в подсчете.
Например выставлен диапазон: 01.01.2020-10.01.2020,то за 10.01 данные не учитываются в подсчете, то есть фактически получается  идет подсчет в диапазоне с 01.01.2020-09.01.2020 включительно.
Пробовал условия переставлять местами и тп, хз без изменений. Получается операторЫ ">=" в первом условии правильно работают, во втором нет???? Может баг? Подскажите парни.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего дело в том, что у даты есть время. Ты хочешь, чтобы дата была `<=`, но если у сравниваемой даты время ненулевое, то она будет больше такой же даты с нулевым временем (я так понимаю, диапазон вводится руками, значит там всегда полночь). В таком случае можно добавить 1 день и сравнивать на `<`. Ещё можно попытаться отбросить время использовав функцию `int`.

Comment: Спасибо. Да, действительно дата со временем, добавил в условие ``INT". Все ок.